# Runtime error: Array of Lists with generics in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, hashtable

I'm attempting the following to implement a separate chaining hash table with generics:

```
// hash table class
protected List<HashEntry<K, V>>[] bucket;
this.bucket = (List<HashEntry<K, V>>[]) new Object[capacity];(*)
(...)
// main program
HashTableMapSC<Integer, String> hashSC = new HashTableMapSC<Integer,String>(7);
```

I get the following run-time error:

> [Ltablashash.HashTableMapSC$HashEntry; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.List;

located at (*)

HashEntry is just a simple private class that holds key,pair values.

I'm aware that this would work:

```
protected List<List<HashEntry<K,V>>> bucket;
```

but as I'm been asked to do it that way,I would like to know if it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you definitely need an array of generics (which is usually discouraged), use

```
this.bucket = new List[capacity];
```

You will have a rawtypes warning though.

Comment: It should be new ArrayList, is't it?

Comment: @SurendarKannan, nope. It's an array of objects, not objects themselves, thus interface type is ok here.

Comment: that indeed works, thank you. I got the following warning:"Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations", but program works as expected